# cPanel Tomcat7 with domain fails to redirect spring security url j_spring_security_check

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security, cpanel

I am using cpanel WHM 11.44 (supports tomcat 7.0.42) on my Centos VPS. I have creating a domain (www.testdomain.com) using WHM and install servlet on it.

Inside **/home/testdomain/**   *jsptest.jsp* is created and successfully loaded that page. On that I have uploaded my spring mvc application with spring security(MyApps.war). My application MyApps.war is extracted inside /home/testdomain.

As per cpanel tomcat7 documentation, I have added **JkMount /MyApps/* ajp13** on cp_jkmount.conf file.
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Introduction+to+Tomcat

Now I can access my tomcat application using **www.testdomain.com/MyApps**. That is successfully loaded and redirected to www.testdomain.com/MyApps/index.jsp. (login page)

After login I can see www.testdomain.com/MyApps/j_spring_security_check with error message. 
(*Not Found : The requested URL /MyApps/j_spring_security_check was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache Server at www.testdomain.com Port 80*).

**Actually MyApps is working fine on my local computer.**

I know cPanel Tomcat 7 is shared on each domains. So What I am missing on shared tomcat with spring security. Please help me move forward.